# How to run Maven test phase before Flyway plugin goal?

Tags: java, maven, flyway

I have the following configuration in my pom.xml file. I am trying to force the **Test** phase to be run automatically when the **flyway:migrate** goal is invoked. I've tried the recommended executions, execution, phase and goals configuration to no avail. Does any one know how to configure this pom.xml properly to achieve that?

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.flywaydb</groupId>
            <artifactId>flyway-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.3</version>
            <configuration>
                <url>${flyway.configuration.url}</url>
                <user>postgres</user>
                <password>secret</password>
                <cleanDisabled>true</cleanDisabled>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>1-test</id>
                    <phase>test</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>info</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: Can you please add a snippet of the `test` phase from Mavens output?

Comment: No test in run at all :( flyway:info runs as expected, however no tests are run.